# How to calculate complex integral with parameter in Python? (CTFT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers, integral

I need to calculate CTFT (Continuous Time Fourier Transform) in Python. In other words: I need to calculate an integral with complex number and parameter.

I have function:

```
def x(t):
    return (np.exp(-2*(t**2)+1))
```

and then I have to calculate integral from:

[image]

w is a parameter here.

where my x(t) is like I wrote before:

[image]

Do you have any advices how to calculate that?

I tried something like that:

```
from sympy.abc import x
w=Symbol('w')
f = exp(-(2*x**2-1-(1j)*w*x))
integrate(f, (x, -np.inf, np.inf))
```

but the result is not good:

[image]

thanks for any advices

Comment: What's the issue, isn't that the solved integral?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a proper solution, cause the result is so long with erf. Is there any other way to calculate that?

Comment: You could check out if ```numpy``` has some method, I'm not sure though

Comment: Any table of fourier transforms will have that one, its another gaussian. Eg https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/ee/yoder/ece380/Handouts/Fourier%20Transform%20Tables%20w.pdf